# Check which string in certain column is repeated

Tags: awk, grep

I want to see which string in my column 2 is repeated.

For example:

```
a   apple
b   peach
c   grape
d   peach
e   peach
f   apple
```

My output would be:

```
a   apple
f   apple
b   peach
d   peach
e   peach
```

Showing the whole line that has common string on second column.

Answer (score 3):

If you do not want to store all the file in memory, the best thing is to read the file twice.

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR {a[$2]++; next} a[$2]>1' file file
a   apple
b   peach
d   peach
e   peach
f   apple
```

- firstly to count how many times a column value appears
- secondly to print rows in which the second column was counted at least twice.

As [Jonathan Leffler suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26259931/check-which-string-in-certain-column-is-repeated/26260013#comment41195268_26260013), to reproduce the exact output you are getting, just pipe to `sort` indicating that it should sort firstly by column 2 and then by column 1:

```
awk 'FNR==NR {a[$2]++; next} a[$2]>1' file file | sort -k2,2 -k1
```

Comment: +1 though the quibblers amongst us might note that the original output has all the apples listed adjacent to each other in the output, and before all the peaches.  That would probably be most easily fixed by sorting the output from your script on the second column: `| sort -k2` or perhaps `| sort -k2,2 -k1`.  It could also be done in `awk`, more easily if the files are small enough to fit in memory and much less easily if they are not.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler pretty true. I just updated with your `sort` recommendation. I tend to prefer piping to the tool that handles things best, so in this case I think sorting has a perfect candidate with `| sort` :)

Answer (score 0):

A perl solution that doesn't read the file twice:

```
perl -lane 'push @{$s{$F[1]}},$_; 
            END{
                do{print join "\n", @{$s{$_}} if scalar(@{$s{$_}})>1}for(%s)
            }' file
```

This goes through the file and keeps each line in a hash whose key is the 2st field and whose values are lists of lines. Then, at the end, it will print the lists whose key was seen more than once.

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk for true 2D arrays:

```
gawk '
{ vals[$2][++cnt[$2]] = $0 }
END {
    for (fruit in vals)
        if (cnt[fruit] > 1)
            for (i=1; i<=cnt[fruit]; i++)
                print vals[fruit][i]
}
' file
a   apple
f   apple
b   peach
d   peach
e   peach
```